Jetty Maven Plugin Resource Base will not parse spaces
I have the latest jetty-ee10-maven-plugin installed on my application, and when I attempt to run it it gives me the following error.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad resourceBases: [/home/user/MyApp/Git Repository/MyApp/MyApp - Local Server/src/main/webapp, /home/user/MyApp/Git Repository/MyApp/target/war/]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.maven.plugin.MavenWebAppContext.setResourceBases(MavenWebAppContext.java:241)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 20: /home/user/MyApp/Git Repository/MyApp/MyApp - Local Server/src/main/webapp
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:932)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1024)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.maven.plugin.MavenWebAppContext.setResourceBases(MavenWebAppContext.java:235)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 20: /home/user/MyApp/Git Repository/MyApp/MyApp - Local Server/src/main/webapp
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2995)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3166)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3248)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3207)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:645)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:930)

The ResourceBases I provided have spaces in the path, which can't be parsed it seems. Unfortunately, removing the spaces from this path is not as simple as it sounds.
Below is the plugin section in the pom.xml for the jetty-ee10-maven-plugin.
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.ee10</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-ee10-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <scan>1</scan>
          <contextXml>${basedir}/src/main/jettyconf/context.xml</contextXml> 
          <jvmArgs>-Xms1G -Xmx4G</jvmArgs>
          <httpConnector>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <port>8888</port>
          </httpConnector>
          <webApp>
            <resourceBases>
              <resourceBase>/home/user/MyApp/Git Repository/MyApp/MyApp - Local Server/src/main/webapp</resourceBase>
              <resourceBase>/home/usser/MyApp/Git Repository/Brainex/target/war/</resourceBase>
            </resourceBases>
          </webApp>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

I have included the full path in the resourceBase section above, but normally these values are set to:
${basedir}/src/main/webapp
and 
${project.parent.build.directory}/war/

So any manual substitution (like replacing the spaces with %20) is not ideal.
I tried every escaping method I could think of. I tried using %20 so the URI parser would work but the % was escaped before making it to the URI parser. Also tried using backslash to escape the %, to escape the space, and I tried xml escaped spaces as well. I tried surrounding it with quotes, but the URI said that they were an illegal character as well.
Is there any way to escape the entire resourceBase tag? Or any way to get Jetty to parse it without using java.net.URI?

This path: <resourceBase>/home/user/MyApp/Git Repository/MyApp/MyApp - Local Server/src/main/webapp</resourceBase> looks wrong it's absolute path...

It is intended to be an absolute path. That path is what is calculated when the same code is run with <resourceBase>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</resourceBase> as the value. I included the absolute path for the purpose of this question because it demonstrates the whitespace problem.

You should not use absolute paths here even the docs: https://jetty.org/docs/jetty/12/programming-guide/maven-jetty/jetty-maven-plugin.html#using-multiple-webapp-root-directories do not use absolute path... just use relative... the second parts is outside of the given project that looks even more strange...

Just got off the phone with the developers of the plugin, this is a bug. Absolute paths should have no problem here, and the doc link you provided even has an example of one. Here is the link for the issue on Git in case you're interested: https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/12000

This was caused by the following issue: https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/12000
It should be resolved by the next release of the plugin in early August 2024.
